# Converting Map[String, Seq[Int]] to Seq[Seq[Int]]

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert data that looks like this:

```
val inputData =
  Seq(("STUDY1", "Follow-up", 1),
    ("STUDY1", "Off Study", 2),
    ("STUDY1", "Screening", 3),
    ("STUDY1", "Treatment", 4),
    ("STUDY2", "Follow-up", 5),
    ("STUDY2", "Off Study", 6),
    ("STUDY2", "Screening", 7),
    ("STUDY2", "Treatment", 8));
```

into data that looks like this:

```
val desiredData =
  Seq(Seq(1,2,3,4),
    Seq(5,6,7,8));
```

The closest that I've gotten is with this:

```
val result: Map[String, Seq[Int]] =
  data.groupBy(i => i._1)
    .mapValues(j => j.map(k => k._3))
    .mapValues(_.toArray)

result.values.toSeq
```

This yields:

```
res0: Seq[Seq[Int]] = Stream(WrappedArray(1, 2, 3, 4), ?)
```

That last question mark is throwing me for a loop.

**EDIT**
Future internet travelers who land here: my code actually *did* work ... my confusion stemmed from understanding what the `?` was all about. Answers from folks down below helped me see that `mapValues` did lazy evaluation, and that the `?` simply implies that.

Comment: Note that your `desiredData` is slightly misleading. I assume you wanted `Seq(Seq(1,2,3,4), Seq(5,6,7,8))`. (What you currently have is of type: `Seq[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]` and not `Seq[Seq[Int]]`)

Comment: @gzm0 thanks for catching that. it is now fixed.

Comment: Hold on, what do you mean by "throwing me for a loop"? Is this actually looping or do you just not understand what `?` means in this context? I tried this and it doesn't loop (on 2.11.7). So `?` essentially means that the tail of the stream is lazily evaluated and not evaluated here (this is to prevent infinite loops in case of infinite streams).

Comment: @gzm0 sorry for the confusion. my choice of words wasn't great. what I mean was that I didn't understand the `?` mean in this context.

Comment: Btw, the above code works. I am not sure what the question is here?

Comment: @marios the question stemmed from my confusion about the `?` ... i didn't realize there were values that were being lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mapValues` on `Map` is lazy (unlike any other method on a default `Map`). So that might be the issue there. Have you tried:

```
data.groupBy(_._1).map(_._2.map(_._3).toArray)
```

Note that the `toArray` is completely optional here.

Answer (score 3):

```
val result: List[Seq[Int]] =
  data.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._3)).values.toList
```

Comment: Can you explain why this one works and the OP's doesn't?